# Send download complete notification to web

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my setup, a user send a request from asp.net Core Page to asp.net core api application to generate large .xsl file.
The web api communicates with the database and generates the files.
How can I notify the user when the download is done and send a download url to the user?
Which technology should I use for that?

Comment: Your question is too broad. In general, you'd want to use web sockets (SignalR) to enable server-to-client connections (instead of the only client-initiated connections allowed by HTTP). Do some research, attempt a solution, and if you run into any problems, *then*, you can ask a specific question about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to give a look to [Signal R](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Read the documentation and then you are going to have a clear idea.
It fits with your requirements.

**EDIT**:

SignalR is a library that simplifies adding real-time web functionality to apps.
To use SignalR you need to configure a server side part and a client side part.
Each part can send "messages" to the other side.

SignalR uses hubs to communicate between clients and servers.

A hub is a high-level pipeline that allows a client and server to call methods on each other.

You can connect many client to the same hub and receive the same notification simultaneously.

So that, you can send the message "download done" to the client that contains the download url too.

Source of the example is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio).

here is an example of hub:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace SignalRChat.Hubs
{
   public class ChatHub : Hub
   {
       public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
       {
           await Clients.All.SendAsync("downloadComplete", user, message);
       }
   }
}
```

Your Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ...
        services.AddSignalR();
    }
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
       app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            // ...
            endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
        });
    }
```

here an example in a JS client where you create che connection with the server side SignalR through the hub. Here you can handle incoming messages:

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();
connection.on("downloadComplete", function (user, message) {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: This is not an answer. While SignalR is what the OP should look into, telling them that doesn't qualify as an answer. You either need to provide an example or post this as a comment instead.